# Is there any way to run two GUI at the same time in java

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

Hello there I am new to programming , I just wanted to ask you guys is there any way to open two seperate stages (windows) at the same time inside the same project

Comment: Depends what GUI framework you're using, but yes: both Swing and JavaFX support this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run same java class by different shell at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753782/run-same-java-class-by-different-shell-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can . You probably should specify the library/framework that you are using.

With JavaFX, you can create two different Stages with two different Scenes and launch both of them, though I believe they will share one CPU thread for rendering.